# Placing a django template form variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, templates

I'm trying to render a form by using django, but through javascript. I guess this is more of a javascript question, but still involves django.

This is what I have in my html head:

```
document.getElementById("profiles").innerHTML = 
            "<p id=\"" + member.id + "\">" + {{ form.first_name|default:member.firstName }} + "</p>";
```

Basically, in the html document, there is a div tag that is "profiles", and it will show the first_name input field when the user is authenticated (this is all for testing). The issue is that when django renders the form, it will put it a lot of text that may or may not have quotes around it. How do I render this form? In python its easy, I could have just done a multiline quote by putting """ around everything.

Thank you.